# I cannot start new sessions on remote server

Tags: ssh

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.02 inside QEMU and trying to remote onto it using SSH.  It is running Byobu.  Whenever I try to connect a second SSH session it reconnects to the exisiting session instead of creating a new session which all my other Ubuntu instances (real and virtualised) do.

I've tried setting MaxSessions but this has not made any difference.

please help

Comment: Did you try to reinstall the ssh server?

Comment: What do you have in your startup files? What is your default shell?